# Since I activated BLE State preservation my app drains all the battery

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, batterylevel, ble-state-preservation

I got an app that is connected to a BLE peripheral. It implements state-preservation and restoration for BLE and keeps the connection in background.

When I leave the phone next to the peripheral the peripheral shows that there is an active connection even if the app is not running, and if left for 12 hours, it will **decrease significantly the amount of battery** (even if no data transfer occurred).

Is this a common problem?

I found a similar problem for **geolocation**. Is there a way to set the refresh rate for "BLE State-preservation"?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the battery drain depends on the connection activity between the devices. If there is no activity (service discovery, read/writes) going on, it shouldn't use much battery.

How exactly are you using state restoration? What happens when your app is woken up by the OS, what BLE event did wake it up?